# search within array for most common occurrences

Tags: php, arrays, url, search, text-files

I have a text logfile, containing lines of data separated by " | "

for example

```
date | time | ip | geo-location (city) | page viewed ......
```

I need to find the 10 most occuring "page views" in the text file....

each log of page view is listed as:

```
//pageurl
```

as the log is on seperate lines I am presuming I would be searching for the page urls between

```
// [url name] \r\n
```

how would I code a search to list the top 10 urls and list them into an array....

for example:

```
$url[0]  <<this would be the most occuring url
$url[1]  <<thos would be the second most occuring url
```

and so on..... until I can list them up to:

```
$url[9]  <<which would be the 10th most common url
```

I am not sure how I would search between the " // " and the " \r\n "

and then convert the top 10 most common occurrences into an array...

edit: here is 2x lines of my logs, just to help even more if I can

```
sunday, january 22, 2012 | 16:14:36 | 82.**.***.*** | bolton | //error 
sunday, january 22, 2012 | 17:12:52 | 82.**.***.*** | bolton | //videos
```

Comment: what language or tool omn what platform do you want the solution to work? Or do you only want pseudo code

Comment: i am coding with php on a windows apache server, thanks

Comment: $data = "$time | $ip | $city | $locate" . "$end";     <<<<< this is the code i use to write the data to the text file ......

$end = "\r\n";       <<<<< that is the variable $end that indicates to write new line, maybe this will help with defining the endpoint of the search ..... i thought it was \n but forgot i had to change it to   \r\n so that it would actually create new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information given, here's a rather naïve approach:

```
/* get the contents of the log file */
$log_file = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/log.txt');

/* split the log into an array of lines */
$log_lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $log_file);

/* we don't need the log file anymore, so free up some memory */
unset($log_file);

/* loop through each line */
$page_views = array();
foreach ($log_lines as $line) {
    /* get the text after the last pipe character (the page view), minus the ' //' */
    $page_views[] = ltrim(array_pop(explode('|', $line)), ' /');
}

/* we don't need the array of lines either, so free up that memory */
unset($log_lines);

/* count the frequency of each unique occurrence */
$urls = array_count_values($page_views);

/* sort highest to lowest (may be redundant, I think array_count_values does this) */
arsort($urls, SORT_NUMERIC);

print_r($urls);
/* [page_url] => num page views, ... */

/* that gives you occurrences, but you want a numerical 
   indexed array for a top ten, so... */

$top_ten = array();
$i = 0;
/* loop through the array, and store the keys in a new one until we have 10 of them */
foreach ($urls as $url => $views) {
  if ($i >= 10) break;
  $top_ten[] = $url;
  $i++;
}

print_r($top_ten);
/* [0] => page url, ... */
```

** Script output: **

```
Array
(
    [videos] => 1
    [error ] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => videos
    [1] => error 
)
```

It's not the most optimal solution, and the bigger your log file, the longer it'll take. To this end, you may be better off logging to a database and querying from that.

Comment: i created new php file for this, and just loads blank page (i get this when code error)

i have also tried inserting echo "hello"; at the beginning to see if there is any output and nothing? this code is far too complicated for me to error check lol apologies

Comment: there was a minor syntax error I've since fixed. You'll want to add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the start, to display errors that do occur.

Comment: would it help if i added another seperator group at the end of the [url] in the log file......

maybe if the log file was ****data **** // [url] ++    

could i create an array of all data between the " // " and the " ++ " ...... even if each array value = //[url]++ and not just the data in between the two seperators.....

i cannot find any way of using a wildcard on php, or i would simply create array from searching for " //*++ " but * doesnt work as a wildcard in php

Comment: Have you changed the `path/to/log/file` in my example (second line) to the actual path to your log file?

Comment: still no errors being listed, and i have added it to the php file as the very first lines after the opening php quotes

Comment: yes ive done that, is it specific about a forward slash before directory name? eg ('/dir/file') or ('dir/file')

Comment: '/dir/file' and 'dir/file' are two very different paths. The first is *absolute*, and starts at the root of your server; the second is *relative*, and starts from the current directory the script is run from.

Comment: ok well just moved log file so dont even need to list directory, just file name, and still nothing.... blank page with no errors listed? im confused

Comment: would this be much simpler if i installed mysql ?

Comment: I've tested the code, fixed another minor error, but it's working exactly as expected for me. You'd be better in the long term with a database.

Comment: this works perfect for me, im just doing some extensive testing to see how it reacts, but so far, all is good, thanks so much

Comment: ok nearly working fully.... i have tested it with increments of pages, to check, and the code will only let me use arrays [0] to [9] (which i expected.....) however, when there are more than 10 results for it to search through, it lists them starting at [0] for the lowest count in the whole list, and works its way up to the tenth lowest count @ [9]

.....

This would work perfectly for a "least pages viewed" script but i need the opposite, im going to try some mods now, but maybe you have some suggestions.... thanks

Comment: You just need to either remove the `asort($urls)` line in the script, and if that doesn't work, replace it with `arsort($urls)`. [PHP: Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: changed to arsort() fixed thanks so much, now i can start designing the table to display the info, thanks so much

Comment: i am presuming there is a process that counts how many occurences of each url there are.... is there a way of also listing the count of occurences as another array maybe?

Comment: It's already in the code. You need to be able to read through it and understand what you're doing. Read tutorials online, etc. I can't walk you through the entire process.

Comment: i know that, im not a noob lol, but i have tried assigning all of the variables as arrays, for the numbered count it creates, but they all come up with errors, as im a bit confused, as im not the best array expert, but have been tinkering with strings for a few months

Comment: i have tried everything from $count0 = array_count_values($top_ten[0]); to $urls[0]; and cant figure out how to get the list of page counts to a set of variables for me to utilize.... please help me :) .... ps your profile says your a musicican... you should come to a jam night at the flying shuttle bury http://the-flying-shuttle.com

Comment: extensive trial and error has brought me this .... echo $urls[$top_ten[5]]; and it works..... thanks for all you have done :)

Comment: would there be a way of modifying this so that the command - $page_views[] = ltrim(array_pop(explode('|', $line)), ' /');
.... will list the data from in front of the first " | " ..... i have been trying all night to get this to work, but cant..... the script is very useful, and i would like to use it again on another page for another function, but i am stuggling to get it to read the leginning of the line not the end of the line thanks